# Why cant I add keyframes to my animator in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have a Unity3D animation, but, I can't add keyframes, it only gives me the option of `Add Animation Event`.
 I also noticed that in the Animation component of the object, It doesn't allow me to check the box of enabled, If I turn it on, the checkbox becomes red and when I turn on/off the record keyframe mode the checkbox automatically unchecks...
I dont know if it could be related, but, this object was created copypasting of another object that has animations, I just deleted all of them and created new ones, but I dont know if this could have affected the object, because I have 2 objects create the same way, and they allow me to put keyframes.

Comment: Did you add a new `AnimatorController` or are you using the same controller for both objects? It is normal behaviour that if you enable `Preview` the animator gets disabled since otherwise the animator would override the preview and you wouldn't be able to see the preview's animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up your animation like the following:

1. Select the object you want to animate.
2. Go to the animation window, click 'Create'.
3. Save the animation to the desired folder. You should now have an animator file and an animation file.
4. Be sure the object is selected and add the desired properties on the left and everything should work just fine.

Hope this helps